# Sequelize foreignKey name for multiple belongsToMany not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Only last table is getting correct foreignKey name. Other tables are getting **ContentContentId** as foreignKey which has correct constraints but wrong name.

```
models.Content.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: 'Viewed_Content',
    foreignKey: 'content_id', sourceKey: 'content_id'
});
models.Content.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: 'Shared_Content',
    foreignKey: 'content_id', sourceKey: 'content_id'
});
models.Content.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: 'Liked_Content',
    foreignKey: 'content_id', sourceKey: 'content_id'
});
```

Comment: Can you put more info about the `through` tables? You need to get a specific pattern on your intermediate table for that.

Comment: If you change an order of those definitions a result will be the same?